# Python Kafka consumer reading already read messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka consumer code -

```
def test():
TOPIC = "file_data"
producer = KafkaProducer()
producer.send(TOPIC, "data")
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='latest',
    consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
    group_id="Group2",
    enable_auto_commit=False,
    auto_commit_interval_ms=1000
)
topic_partition = TopicPartition(TOPIC, 0)
assigned_topic = [topic_partition]
consumer.assign(assigned_topic)
consumer.seek_to_beginning(topic_partition)
for message in consumer:
    print("%s key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.key, message.value))
consumer.commit()
```

**Expected behavior**
It should read only the last message which is written by the producer. It should just print:

```
file_data key=None value=b'data'
```

**Current behavior**
After running code it prints:

```
file_data key=None value=b'data'
file_data key=None value=b'data'
file_data key=None value=b'data'
file_data key=None value=b'data'
file_data key=None value=b'data'
file_data key=None value=b'data'
```

Comment: Not an expert on Kafka, but the `consumer.seek_to_beginning` call sounds like it would cause this?

Comment: @JohanSchiff Tried consumer.seek_to_end but it doesnt return anything. No message is read.

Comment: Your code is indented incorrectly. Could you fix that? Otherwise we have to make assumptions on what your actual code is, and that assumptions can be wrong. And it would help if you could provide a [mre] (a piece of code that someone can copy/paste to run and test it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka import TopicPartition
from kafka import KafkaProducer

def test():
    TOPIC = "file_data"
    producer = KafkaProducer()
    producer.send(TOPIC, b'data')
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
        auto_offset_reset='latest',
        consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
        group_id="Group2",
        enable_auto_commit=False,
        auto_commit_interval_ms=1000
    )
    topic_partition = TopicPartition(TOPIC, 0)
    assigned_topic = [topic_partition]
    consumer.assign(assigned_topic)
    # consumer.seek_to_beginning(topic_partition)
    for message in consumer:
        print("%s key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.key, message.value))
    consumer.commit()
test()
```

This is working as per your expectation. If you want it to start at the beginning, then only call `seekToBeginning`

Ref: [seek_to_beginning](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.seek_to_beginning)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `consumer.seek_to_beginning(topic_partition)`, you need to use `consumer.seek_to_end(topic_partition)`.

From docs:

> Kafka allows specifying the position using seek(TopicPartition, long) to specify the new position. Special methods for seeking to the earliest and latest offset the server maintains are also available ( seekToBeginning(Collection) and seekToEnd(Collection) respectively).

In simple form:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('topicName', bootstrap_servers=[server], group_id=group_id, enable_auto_commit=True)
consumer.poll()
consumer.seek_to_end()

for message in consumer:
    print(message)

consumer.close()
```

Comment: consumer.seek_to_end(topic_partition) doesnt show any result. It returns no message.

Comment: The output remain same.All message are retrieved, when enable_auto_commit=true and consumer.seek_to_beginning(topic_partition). Also no message retrieved enable_auto_commit=false and consumer.seek_to_beginning(topic_partition).